# Google App Engine Python: [Errno 10054] XML parse

Tags: xml, sockets, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I am developing an app engine application which relies on webapp2 framework. 
In my case, I needed a lib to parse XML file and I found ElementTree lib which is under my Python directory Python27\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py by the way, Python version is 2.7 and I use its parse method. After parse operation, I am iterating it. Here my relative code snippet:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 tree = ET.parse('myLargeSample.xml')
 root = tree.getroot()

 for item in root.iter('item'):
 # simple count operation
```

In most cases it was worked when I requested its wrapper class which is webapp2 RequestHandler, but now I have a relatively much bigger XML file about 11 MB and when I run the code, I get this error: **[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host** at the end of exception stack.

Not only for this, but also my python.exe consumes up to 2 GB ram which is abnormal when I requested wrapper class! I did not find any close case when I searched because socket error is basic error, I think. Have you any suggestion what would be the problem ? 
I am really stucked with this error, thank you for your answers.

Comment: how much ram does it consume when you do it locally? Is that over the ram you've made available via your instance type?

Comment: Yes this consumption exceeds that I expected, not only but this process consumes % 25 -30 CPU just for itself.